# What do the green and red chevron indicators mean?

Tags: xcom-2

What's the significance of the chevron that occasionally appear on the `Human Health Bar:`

[image]

`Character Name:`

[image]

And on the `Advent Health Bar:`

[image]

I've seen both green and red cheverons.  I'm assuming green is good is a positive buff and red a negative one.  But is there a way to see what's causing these chevrons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They represent temporary status effects which affect the unit. Green represent good status effects (in the first screenshot this seems to be "aid protocol") and red bad status effects (like "poisoned" or "disoriented").

To see which conditions exactly affect the soldier, hover your mouse cursor over the rank-icon in the lower-left corner (the thing in your 2nd screenshot).

Comment: What about enemy status effects, how can you see those?

Comment: @PhilipPittle I don't think there is a way to find out anything about those.

Comment: If you hover over the enemy, or the icon to the left of the enemy's health bar (when it appears), you can often view effects on enemies as well.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Dark Event effects, such as ADVENT being on high alert will apply a negative buff to your whole squad for every mission undertaken whilst the Dark Event is active.